# Узнать, есть ли значение по умолчанию в свойстве

Tags: c#

```
class MyClass {
  public int IntProperty {get; set;}
  public string StrProperty {get; set;} = "Hello"
}
```

Как узнать через рефлексию, установлено ли значение по умолчанию, у свойства IntProperty?

Comment: установленно -- это `0` :)

Comment: Никак, то что вы написали - это не значение по умолчанию. Это синтаксический сахар. На самом деле значение будет установлено в конструкторе.

Comment: можно узнать почему вы задались этим вопросом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через рефлексию (имеются ввиду мета-данные) никак, потому что компилятор такие значения по умолчанию кидает в конструктор. Вот как выглядит конструктор для вашего класса:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
    instance void .ctor () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x20ab
    // Code size 19 (0x13)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldstr "Hello"
    IL_0006: stfld string ConsoleApp1.Program/MyClass::'<StrProperty>k__BackingField'
    IL_000b: ldarg.0
    IL_000c: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    IL_0011: nop
    IL_0012: ret
} // end of method MyClass::.ctor
```

Если вам уж очень нужно такое реализовать, то придется анализировать IL-код конструктора.

Comment: Думаю, и анализ кода конструкторах не поможет: наверняка для инициализации в конструкторе и присвоением свойству генерируется одинаковый IL.